# conditionally close insert </tr><tr> in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have a Component in Vue

I need to add list of 6 items to the table 2x3.

Is there any way to conditionally add "" after every second insert?

```
<template> 
<tr> 
<td>asdasd</td><td>qweqwe</td>
<!-- here i would like to insert </tr><tr> after every second add
 v-if="post.tag%2"? -->
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi @Aziz, I don't understand exactly what you're looking for, but maybe a v-for with an index can help you? E.g. `v-for="(item, index) in items"`.

Comment: yes.sorry. v-for will add one by one, and all inserted elements will have same structure <tr><td>asd</td></tr> i want it to be <tr><td>123</td><td>456</td></tr>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<table>
<tr v-for="i in fruits.length/2"> <!--- create a row for every second item -->
  <td>
    Fruit: {{fruits[i*2]}}
  </td>
  <td v-if="i*2+1 < fruits.length">  <!--- check if there is another item left to display -->
    Fruit: {{fruits[i*2+1]}}
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It's not very elegant, but it does the job! I made a Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/asdasgqq/pen/gObBaZX).